# click event not happening with bootstrap panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my own class with panels that open and close content using Bootstrap and jQuery (not an accordion, I want multiple open at a time). However, the click event isn't working for me and I have no idea why... I tried the "*" selector and the alert was working but it's not working when I try to associate it with specific elements.

### Practice2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Practice 2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/prism.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/styles.css">

    <script src="../static/js/prism.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-toggle" id="demo">
        <div class="panel-heading">solution</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <code class="language-python">
            def solution(self):
                func = self.functionGenerator()
                length = self.endTime - self.initialTime
                timesConcerned = [self.initialTime+x/1000. for x in range(length*1000)]
                return odeint(func,self.initialValues,timesConcerned)
            </code><br>
        Explanation
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### script.js

```
// $(".panel-toggle:panel-header").click(function(){
//  // $(this).next().toggle();
//  alert("hello");
// });

$("#demo").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```

### styles.css

```
.panel-toggle .panel-heading:after {
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content:"\e114";
    float: right;
    color: grey;
}
.panel-toggle .collapsed:after {
    content:"\e080";
}
.panel-toggle .panel-body {

}
```

Clearly the rest of the code needs some adjustment but I'm just troubleshooting this part right now and would appreciate some advice on what I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: your click event is working fine: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41378otd/)

Comment: is code wrapped in *document.ready* handler so elements exist when it runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-toggle">
    <div class="panel-heading">solution</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <code class="language-python">
        def solution(self):
            func = self.functionGenerator()
            length = self.endTime - self.initialTime
            timesConcerned = [self.initialTime+x/1000. for x in range(length*1000)]
            return odeint(func,self.initialValues,timesConcerned)
        </code>
    Explanation
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel-heading").click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

works

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/qp9en30e/)

Answer (score 1):

You should put your jQuery code in document.ready block ensure your code working after those element been generated.

**Script.js** should be changed like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#demo").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

Comment: Should've just done that to start off with, oops. Thanks!

Comment: If your question has been resolved, mark the working answer to make others easily know the status of this question.